# geom_tile() aligning x labels and tick marks

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using geom_tile() and unfortunately the ticks and the x (column) labels are not aligned. While ticks are right in the center of the column, the axis labels are shifted to the right. I tried to add:

theme(axis.title.x = element_text(hjust=-0.5))

but it does not seem to help. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: maybe play around with `size`: `theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=14, angle=90))`

Comment: use `vjust` instead. Even though the labels are rotated, their orientation axis are not, so in your configuration about vjust will move left/right and hjust will move up/down

Comment: it works! Many thanks!